# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method System.Guid

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following error :

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Guid GetIdAuthenticatedUser()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

This happens when I run this code:

```
   ...
 if (_context.Voice.Any(u => u.VoiceUserId == _repository.GetIdAuthenticatedUser())) //error here
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("MainPage.aspx");
                    }
    ...
```

Method `GetIdAuthenticatedUser()` returns to id of the authenticated user:

```
 public Guid GetIdAuthenticatedUser()
        {
            MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
            var a = user.ProviderUserKey;
            var userid = new Guid(a.ToString());
            return userid;
        }
```

**`u.VoiceUserId` is of type `Guid`**

What need to do to make it work?

Comment: You should put the result of `_repository.GetIdAuthenticatedUser()` into a variable before and use that one in the LINQ expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just move the call to the function to outside the linq query

```
var id = _repository.GetIdAuthenticatedUser();
if (_context.Voice.Any(u => u.VoiceUserId == id))
{
    Response.Redirect("MainPage.aspx");
}
```

The problem is that, like the error says, the method GetIdAuthenticatedUser() isnt part of linq so when linq is trying to generate the query for the DB it doesnt know how to translate the method call to sql